# ORA-00439: Oracle Transparent Data Encryption XE 11.2.0

Tags: oracle, tde

I would like to use Oracle Transparent Data Encryption with XE 11.2.0.  I have TDE setup and the wallet opened. However, I'm getting an error when trying to set a field to encrypted.  Is the Advanced Security Option available under the XE edition?

ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Transparent Data Encryption

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Advanced Security Option is not available in Oracle Express Edition 11.2, according to the [Database Express Edition Licensing Information](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#XELIC116).